# Discrete Fourier transformation

Tags: matlab

```
gauss=exp(-(x.^2+y.^2)/scale(i)^2);

gaus=gauss/sum(gauss(:));
x=fft2(gaus,size(image,1),size(image,2));
```

I want to ask about this part of codein MATLAB

1. What is the meaning of colon here  (gauss(:))
2. I want to implement  the  Discrete Fourier transformation in ( x)
   by MAY OWN FUNCTION,Can I apply DFT to every three component 
   independently  and then add the result together?

Answer (score 1):

1) The colon operator reshapes the matrix into a vector.

2) You can transform each sample separately.

Comment: Can you tell me after transform each samples how can I put them all in varible x for example ?

Comment: I suggest you'd read the Getting Started with MATLAB document: http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/getstart.pdf.